# split list of strings based on string in the list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need your help with this
I have a list like this

```
list = ['Acura of Columbus', '303 Veterans Memorial Pkwy', 'Lanett,', 'AL', '36863', '(334) 576-6700', 'ID:68602', 'Adventure Chevrolet', '106 1st Ave', 'Brewton,', 'AL', '36426', '(205) 375-2521', 'ID:68603', ...]
```

I want to split this long list into sublists based on the 'ID:'
so the new list will be like this

```
new_list = [['Acura of Columbus', '303 Veterans Memorial Pkwy', 'Lanett,', 'AL', '36863', '(334) 576-6700'],['Adventure Chevrolet', '106 1st Ave', 'Brewton,', 'AL', '36426', '(205) 375-2521']]
```

I have tried this code

```
for item in list:
        if item.startswith('ID:'):
            print(list[:list.index(item)])
```

but it doesn't work with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` is a reserved word, don't use it. I change the name of the list to `list_`. Below you can find the code that generates a 2D list based on **ID's**

```py
list_ = ['Acura of Columbus', '303 Veterans Memorial Pkwy', 'Lanett,', 'AL', '36863', '(334) 576-6700', 'ID:68602', 'Adventure Chevrolet', '106 1st Ave', 'Brewton,', 'AL', '36426', '(205) 375-2521', 'ID:68603']
prev= 0
new_list = []
for item in list_:
        if item.startswith('ID:'):
            new_list.append(list_[prev:list_.index(item) + 1])
            prev = list_.index(item) + 1
new_list
```

Output:

```py
[['Acura of Columbus',
  '303 Veterans Memorial Pkwy',
  'Lanett,',
  'AL',
  '36863',
  '(334) 576-6700',
  'ID:68602'],
 ['Adventure Chevrolet',
  '106 1st Ave',
  'Brewton,',
  'AL',
  '36426',
  '(205) 375-2521',
  'ID:68603']]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not use a built-in class name such as `list` for a variable name.

Using a generator function makes the logic particularly simple:

```py
def generate_lists(lst):
    
    def generate_lists_helper(lst):
        l = []
        for elem in lst:
            l.append(elem)
            if elem.startswith('ID:'):
                yield l
                l = []
        if l:
            yield l

    return list(generate_lists_helper(lst))


lst = ['Acura of Columbus', '303 Veterans Memorial Pkwy', 'Lanett,', 'AL', '36863', '(334) 576-6700', 'ID:68602', 'Adventure Chevrolet', '106 1st Ave', 'Brewton,', 'AL', '36426', '(205) 375-2521', 'ID:68603']
print(generate_lists(lst))
```

Prints:

```
[['Acura of Columbus', '303 Veterans Memorial Pkwy', 'Lanett,', 'AL', '36863', '(334) 576-6700', 'ID:68602'], ['Adventure Chevrolet', '106 1st Ave', 'Brewton,', 'AL', '36426', '(205) 375-2521', 'ID:68603']]
```